# Eclipse git UI throws error

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am working on windows and use eclipse for commit and pull from remote git repository. Recently one of the developer committed file from Mac-OS when I pulled the same file in my local repository, eclipse started giving me following error

> Error occurred computing Git commit diffs Invalid path:
>   ms-postman/src/main/resources/fonts.xml

Error logs in eclipse:

```
Error occurred computing Git commit diffs
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Invalid path: ms-postman/src/main/resources/fonts.xml 
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheEntry.<init>(DirCacheEntry.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.readFrom(DirCache.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.read(DirCache.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.read(DirCache.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.read(DirCache.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.readDirCache(Repository.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.IndexDiff.diff(IndexDiff.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitUI.getIndexDiff(CommitUI.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.CommitActionHandler$2.run(CommitActionHandler.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: invalid name ends with ' '
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectChecker.report(ObjectChecker.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectChecker.checkPathSegment2(ObjectChecker.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectChecker.checkPathSegment(ObjectChecker.java:787)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectChecker.checkPath(ObjectChecker.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.checkPath(SystemReader.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheEntry.checkPath(DirCacheEntry.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheEntry.<init>(DirCacheEntry.java:195)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: "org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: invalid name ends with ' '"

Comment: Could you just ask the developer to rename the file? I believe it does not integrate properly into project, even if checked out.

Comment: Ok I shall ask, but when I myself tried to rename the file in local repository, error still persists

Comment: Once developer removed file, eclipse stopped giving error

Answer (score 0):

After another developer renamed the file and did git pull then it stopped giving this error. So there was issue in file name itself.